# Pytractor throwing find_element_by_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'descriptor'

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, protractor, selenium-iedriver

I am writing the Automated script to work with angular and non-angular applications - in fact, once browser is opened, it will have a few re-directions before it gets to needed page with an angular app. I can handle it by timeouts and selenium, but i cannot find ng-model elements. I am trying now:

*Code Updated*

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pytractor.webdriver import Ie

wd = Ie(base_url='http://localhost:8080/base_url', script_timeout=50) #timeout does not work here by some reason
wd.ignoreSynchronization = True
wd.get('link')
time.sleep(40)
```

Also, due to synchronization page does not load further

And in the end i am receiving:

> AngularNotFoundException: Message: Angular could not be found on page: link : retries looking for angular exceeded

Any advice?

Thank you in advance.

The structure of the web-part i am trying to attend is (in stars ***********):

```
<div class="table-scrollInvoice">



            <table ng-show="true" class="table-bordered tableInvoice">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice"><input ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">WBSE Number</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">WBSE Description</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Project Profile</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Line Item - Material Code Details <a style="margin-left: 15px;" href="#" class="btn-icon icon-info" title="" data-original-title="The field 'Line Item - Material Code Details' is a mandatory field"></a></th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="hideTimeSupply">Time of Supply</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-binding">Material Sales Text / Line Item Text</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice" ng-show="hideQuantity">Quantity</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false">Display Quantity?</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Material Code Type</th>             
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="hideAdditional">Additional Information</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false">Line Item Category</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false">Tax</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false">Condition Type</th>         
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Amount</th>                                     
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Are you contractually obligated to bill reimbursable expenses as services revenue? (This is not common)</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice">Amount of expenses to bill as fees</th>
                    <th class="thCustomInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false">Condition Type 2</th></tr>
                <!-- ngRepeat: costObj in invoice --><tr ng-repeat="costObj in invoice" class="ng-scope">
                    <td><input class="checkBoxInvoice ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" type="checkbox" ng-model="costObj.selected" ng-change="checkBoxEnablrBtn()"></td>

                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.selectedName" ng-change="callSapWEb(costObj.selectedName ,$index, costObj)" ng-options="wbsnum.idWbs as wbsnum.nameWbs for wbsnum in names"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="A6WG1001">A6WG1001</option></select></td>
                    <td><input class="myDescription ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="costObj.Description" disabled="disabled"></td>

                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="costObj.selectedProfile" ng-change="onChangeProf(costObj.selectedProfile , $index)" ng-options="prof.id as prof.name for prof in profile" disabled="disabled"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="Consulting">Consulting</option><option value="1" label="Outsourcing">Outsourcing</option></select></td>




                    <td>
                        <select ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" class="myTdropDownLineItem ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialCodeDetails" ng-change="onChangeLineItem(costObj.MaterialCodeDetails,costObj.selectedName,$index)" ng-options="materialLine.nameContract as materialLine.nameContract for materialLine in costObj.materialLineDetails"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="000010 - S00600 - Services">000010 - S00600 - Services</option><option value="1" label="000020 - S06600 - Reimbursable Expenses">000020 - S06600 - Reimbursable Expenses</option></select></td>

                    <td ng-show="hideTimeSupply" class="ng-hide"><input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="DatePicker ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength" type="text" maxlength="10" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.TimeOfSupply" ng-blur="dateValidator(costObj.TimeOfSupply,$index)"></td>



                    <td><textarea class="mySalesText ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialSales" ng-blur="everyChangeOfFieldInvoice()" ng-disabled="disableMaterialSales"></textarea></td>


             <td ng-show="hideQuantity"><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Quantity" ng-blur="getValueAmount()"></td>      

                    <td ng-show="false" class="ng-hide">
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.DisplayQuantity" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-options="displayQuan.id as displayQuan.name  for displayQuan in displayQuantity"><option value="0" label="Yes">Yes</option><option value="1" selected="selected" label="No">No</option></select></td>



                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialType" ng-disabled="true" ng-change="onChangeMaterialTypeVal(costObj.MaterialType, $index)" ng-options="materialTypes.id as materialTypes.name for materialTypes in materialTypeVal" disabled="disabled"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="Fees">Fees</option><option value="1" label="Expenses">Expenses</option></select></td>

                    **<td ng-show="hideAdditional" class="ng-hide"><textarea class="myTLocalDropAddInformation ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Additional"></textarea></td>**
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.LineItemCategory" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.Tax" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>       
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.ConditionType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>
                    *****************<td><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Amount" ng-blur="getValueAmount()"></td>********************
                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDropContratually ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.Contractually" ng-change="contractuallyCall(costObj.Contractually,$index)" ng-disabled="costObj.disableContractually" ng-options="contractually for contractually in contractuallyYesNo"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" label="Yes">Yes</option><option value="1" selected="selected" label="No">No</option></select></td>
                    <td><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-change="onChangeEpenseBill(costObj.expensesTobill,$index)" ng-disabled="costObj.disableExpense" ng-model="costObj.expensesTobill" disabled="disabled"></td>            
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.ConditionType2" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td></tr><!-- end ngRepeat: costObj in invoice --><tr ng-repeat="costObj in invoice" class="ng-scope">
                    <td><input class="checkBoxInvoice ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" type="checkbox" ng-model="costObj.selected" ng-change="checkBoxEnablrBtn()"></td>

                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.selectedName" ng-change="callSapWEb(costObj.selectedName ,$index, costObj)" ng-options="wbsnum.idWbs as wbsnum.nameWbs for wbsnum in names"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="A6WG1001">A6WG1001</option></select></td>
                    <td><input class="myDescription ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="costObj.Description" disabled="disabled"></td>

                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="costObj.selectedProfile" ng-change="onChangeProf(costObj.selectedProfile , $index)" ng-options="prof.id as prof.name for prof in profile" disabled="disabled"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="Consulting">Consulting</option><option value="1" label="Outsourcing">Outsourcing</option></select></td>




                    <td>
                        <select ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" class="myTdropDownLineItem ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialCodeDetails" ng-change="onChangeLineItem(costObj.MaterialCodeDetails,costObj.selectedName,$index)" ng-options="materialLine.nameContract as materialLine.nameContract for materialLine in costObj.materialLineDetails"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" label="000010 - S00600 - Services">000010 - S00600 - Services</option><option value="1" label="000020 - S06600 - Reimbursable Expenses">000020 - S06600 - Reimbursable Expenses</option></select></td>

                    <td ng-show="hideTimeSupply" class="ng-hide"><input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="DatePicker ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength" type="text" maxlength="10" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.TimeOfSupply" ng-blur="dateValidator(costObj.TimeOfSupply,$index)"></td>



                    <td><textarea class="mySalesText ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialSales" ng-blur="everyChangeOfFieldInvoice()" ng-disabled="disableMaterialSales"></textarea></td>


             <td ng-show="hideQuantity"><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Quantity" ng-blur="getValueAmount()"></td>      

                    <td ng-show="false" class="ng-hide">
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.DisplayQuantity" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-options="displayQuan.id as displayQuan.name  for displayQuan in displayQuantity"><option value="0" label="Yes">Yes</option><option value="1" selected="selected" label="No">No</option></select></td>



                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.MaterialType" ng-disabled="true" ng-change="onChangeMaterialTypeVal(costObj.MaterialType, $index)" ng-options="materialTypes.id as materialTypes.name for materialTypes in materialTypeVal" disabled="disabled"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" label="Fees">Fees</option><option value="1" label="Expenses">Expenses</option></select></td>

                    <td ng-show="hideAdditional" class="ng-hide"><textarea class="myTLocalDropAddInformation ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Additional"></textarea></td>
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.LineItemCategory" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.Tax" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>       
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.ConditionType" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td>
                    ******************<td><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Amount" ng-blur="getValueAmount()"></td>  *****************
                    <td>
                        <select class="myTLocalDropContratually ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="costObj.Contractually" ng-change="contractuallyCall(costObj.Contractually,$index)" ng-disabled="costObj.disableContractually" ng-options="contractually for contractually in contractuallyYesNo" disabled="disabled"><option value="" class="">-- None --</option><option value="0" label="Yes">Yes</option><option value="1" label="No">No</option></select></td>
                    <td><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-change="onChangeEpenseBill(costObj.expensesTobill,$index)" ng-disabled="costObj.disableExpense" ng-model="costObj.expensesTobill" disabled="disabled"></td>            
                    <td class="myTdInvoice ng-hide" ng-show="false"><input ng-model="costObj.ConditionType2" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></td></tr><!-- end ngRepeat: costObj in invoice --></tbody></table>
            <br><br></div>
```

Comment: Updated the code, still need help

Comment: try adding wd.waitForAngularEnabled(false); before the .get

Comment: @JeremyKahan I have updated it 'wd = Ie(base_url='http://localhost:8080/base_url', script_timeout=50)
wd.ignoreSynchronization = True
wd.wait_for_angular = False
wd.get('link')
time.sleep(40)' , but the same issue appears :(

Comment: I'm not sure about setting wait_for_angular directly is the same as the call I suggested, but looking at their code on https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.3.2/lib/browser.ts I see the (deprecated?) setting of ignoreSynchronization should already have made the call I was suggesting, so it must be something else. Here is a thought. Sometimes the change in setting takes time to happen, so perhaps a sleep before the .get().

Comment: @JeremyKahan still no luck. If i have wd.ignore_synchronization = True it stops to make redirections over the pages. Timout before get() also did not help. Besides i have tried: wd.wait_for_angular() as well as wd.set_script_timeout(). By no reason it ignores all these timeouts...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`wd.ignoreSynchronization = True`

Try

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

"ignoreSynchronization" is being deprecated and eventually will no longer be available. It is possible to not work.

Comment: The same AngularNotFoundException . It looks like the script ignores all these methods and functions and jumps straight to getting url. Is there any other way to find angularJS element on the web maybe?

Comment: When you are on not angular page selectors are like selenium like this example: browser.driver.findElement(by.id("id")) . You can't use element.by()

Comment: yes, i know. i can access page if i am using selenium only. But the page has angular forms, which i need an access to. That why i am using pytractor for that. And it stops script each time it opens the first redirection page which does not have Angular JS in it... i need somehow tell the pytractor to wait untill the page is loaded, and all the methods above does not work, unfortunatly

Comment: The element on the page looks like this: <td><input class="myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-disabled="disableAllBaseOnStage" ng-model="costObj.Amount" ng-blur="getValueAmount()"></td>. I have tried to access it via selenium's find by class - i have failed

Comment: Before every angular page action you should have this: browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);

Comment: That is angular element. So you can use element(by.model("costObj.Amount")); of protractor. Please note that this is in Java Script.

Comment: wd = Ie(base_url='http://localhost:8080/base_url')
wd.wait_for_angular = True
wd.get('link')
time.sleep(10) - still the same error... regarding searching by element i have tried - wd.find_element_by_class_name('myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched')  and result was - cannot find this element

Comment: I have updated the question with the part of code i am trying to access...any tips how to get there? search by class did not help

Comment: Do you see the element when the test fails? Add wait before interacting with element
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.model("costObj.Amount")))), 30000, "Element is not visible");

Comment: If you don't see element use ExpectedConditions to wait to become visible.

Comment: i am trying this - wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    AMOUNTFIELD = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'myTLocalDrop ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'))) element gets visible on page, but i am getting TimeOut error

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! CHANGED to AMOUNTFIELD = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[ng-model="costObj.Amount"]'))) !!!! THANK YOU EVERYONE!!!